# Logging into profiles with Tor

Tags: security

I am reading that logging into diferent profiles on diferent platforms will make me loose my protection.

But if i log out and start a new Tor session, shouldnt i appear as another person and regain my protection? Or have i affected my protection permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by logging into different websites using the Tor browser, you lose your anonymity since the website can fingerprint/track you. But by starting a new Tor session, you regain you anonymity. There is no permanent effect.

By clicking the `New identity` button or closing the Tor browser and reopening it, all cookies/trackers placed on your previous session are cleared and a new Tor circuit is created (which is done every time a new website is visited anyways).

If you want a more in-depth version of what the `New Identity` button does, visit: https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#new-identity.